# asyncio doesn't work on listening to the http request

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am running `aiohttp` as my server. When a request comes in, I try to spawn a process to handle it. But I get the below error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "asyncppx.py", line 33, in
>   
>       app.add_routes([web.get('/', asyncio.ensure_future(runMcows(n)))])   File
>   "/Users/i3ye/Programming/vsc/async/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/web_app.py",
>   line 231, in add_routes
>       self.router.add_routes(routes)   File "/Users/i3ye/Programming/vsc/async/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/web_urldispatcher.py",
>   line 966, in add_routes
>       route_obj.register(self)   File "/Users/i3ye/Programming/vsc/async/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/web_routedef.py",
>   line 38, in register
>       reg(self.path, self.handler, **self.kwargs)   File "/Users/i3ye/Programming/vsc/async/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/web_urldispatcher.py",
>   line 922, in add_get
>       resource.add_route(hdrs.METH_HEAD, handler, **kwargs)   File "/Users/i3ye/Programming/vsc/async/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/web_urldispatcher.py",
>   line 269, in add_route
>       expect_handler=expect_handler)   File "/Users/i3ye/Programming/vsc/async/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/web_urldispatcher.py",
>   line 682, in **init**
>       resource=resource)   File "/Users/i3ye/Programming/vsc/async/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/web_urldispatcher.py",
>   line 103, in **init**
>       assert callable(handler), handler AssertionError: > Task was destroyed but it
>   is pending! task: > sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'runMcows' was never
>   awaited

The code is below, any suggestions?

```
from aiohttp import web
import aiohttp
import asyncio

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

#tasks = []
n = 0

def mcowA(n):
   print (n, " : A") 
   return

async def fetch(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        return await response.text()

def mcowB(n):
   print (n, " : B") 
   return

async def runMcows(n):
    mcowA(n)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        html = await fetch(session, 'http://localhost:8081')
    mcowB(n)
    return html


try:
    app = web.Application()
    app.add_routes([web.get('/', asyncio.ensure_future(runMcows(n)))])
    loop.run_forever()
    web.run_app(app)
finally:
    loop.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the server example [here](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#getting-started):

Your code should be like this in the main execution:

```
app = web.Application()
app.add_routes([web.get('/', runMcows])
web.run_app(app)
```

`app.add_routes` You need to pass a coroutine `runMcows` which can only take 1 variable, the request itself.

```
async def runMcows(request):
    mcowA(n)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        html = await fetch(session, 'http://localhost:8081')
    mcowB(n)
    return web.Response(text=html)  # Change this response type based on what you need.
```

Comment: In this case, the server servers one request at a time. If I get 100 requests, I want the code to go out to fetch in parallel.

Comment: @rickcoup Why do you think the server serves one request at a time? The `await` in the answer only suspends the *current* coroutine, it doesn't affect other coroutines that serve other requests.

Comment: This is the first thing that I tried.  It doesn't even server the second request until finish all three functions of the first request.

Comment: @rickcoup How did you determine that? The code shown in the question is incorrect in several ways, and the answer shows how to fix it. For an additional test, I've now tried running a similarly corrected [modified version](https://pastebin.com/t9gL0v7k). I've also run `nc -lp8081`, so that the `fetch` can connect but is left hanging. If I connect with multiple clients, I see that the request object is printed even though the previous request didn't finish, which means the requests are run in parallel. If you are running the corrected code and see something different, please edit the question.